# Asp.net css not working properly after publish

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012, publish

I have an ASP.Net (.net 4.0) page, which contains javascript, css and custom controls.

When I debug the Page, everything looks fine and is working properly. But after publishing, some css don't work anymore. But most of them do. Although they are from the same css file.

I.E.
I have table-data (`<td>`) tags, which have a select-box in it. In debug, the select-box is visible (width of select: 85%) but in published, the select-box is really thin, because the td doesn't have any width and 85% of 0 is... not much ;).

Also I am not able to hide and unhide divs in my page via JavaScript anymore. I just set display to block or none, but my divs are hidden always, while in debug they work.

I saw problems regarding the including path of css and script files (with root or without root directory etc), tried it but it didn't solve the problem.

Another source said, it would be because of the compatibility mode to .net 3.5, which I changed to 4.0 and it didn't solve the problem, also.

Do you have any idea what could happen here?

For example, the header of a table:

In InternetExplorer while debugging:

[image]

And in InternetExplorer after publishing:

[image]

You can see there is a gap between the `<td>` Tags.

Comment: Are all files published? Can we see your live site?

Comment: All files are published. Sorry, this is not possible. But I can provide screenshots so you can see, that there are some differences.

Comment: Can be ca cache issue? Have you tried to clear it?

Comment: can you print the whole html for the specific section, as well as the css it's using? otherwise it's rather difficult to help seeing how bad it is to fix IE problems in general

Comment: if you view source and click on the css file link, what happens?

Comment: Cache is not the problem. I already cleared it, very often. If I view the source-code it shows me the css, that it supposed to use. It is identical to the one I am using in debug. I try to get a Short html example to work, which shows the problem but is simple to read